# Boolean Algebra simplification (3 inputs)

Tags: input, boolean, algebra, simplification

I may need your help with this quite simple thing:
This -> `abc' + ab'c + a'bc + abc`
can (I guess) be simplified to this -> `ab+ac+bc`.

But how in the world is this done with `Boolean` algebra?

I already reduced it to -> abc'+ab'c+bc by using the absorption rule on the last two terms `[a'bc + abc]`. But how can I reduce the rest of it to get the end result?

Comment: If you just google "boolean evaluator" or something you will find web sites that will simplify your expression ***and*** list the rules they used to simplify it.  "Wolfram Alpha" is known to be a good one.

Comment: Try using de-morgans law as well

Comment: thanks, I already tried wolfram alpha and another one (in german). they all come to the same result. but there is no real explanation for the result. For example, they say: "a~bc + ab" results in "ac + ab". But they do not say WHY :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before simplifying the expression I'll show you one nice trick that will be used later. For any two logical variables A and B the following holds:

```
A + AB = A(B + 1) = A
```

With this in mind let's simplify your expression:

```
abc' + ab'c + a'bc + abc = ac(b + b') + abc' + a'bc = ac + abc' + a'bc
```

We can expand `ac` in the following way using that '*trick*' I mentioned before:

```
ac = ac + abc = ac(b + 1) = ac
```

Using this we get:

```
ac + abc' + a'bc = 
ac + abc + abc' + a'bc =
ac + ab(c + c') + a'bc = 
ac + ab + a'bc =
ac + ab + abc + a'bc =
ab + bc(a + a') + ac =
ab + ac + bc
```

Leading to the final expression you wanted to get in the first place.